# How to run unit tests with test specific class

Tags: android, unit-testing

I have a class that I need to replace with a dummy class when I'm running tests. Is there a way to achieve this? I know product flavors offer something like this so I imagine this should be possible too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [PowerMock](https://github.com/jayway/powermock). It allows you to mock static methods and contructors to return mocked objects (and more).

Comment: So this is perfect for me but turns out if I include this I have to enable mulitdexing which sounds like a waste. Is there any other way to do this? Thanks either way.